# AWS CodeBuild throws an error 127, SNI not available

Tags: aws-codebuild

I was running the code build when it threw this error

```
[Container] 2018/10/18 00:43:55 Running command $(aws ecs stop-task --task arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:502776083946:task/207cfc8b-914d-4c4b-9c8a-0ffbfcef6924 --cluster arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:502776083946:cluster/timesheet-staging-cluster)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:369: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
SNIMissingWarning
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: {: not found
```

How do I resolve this? I need the ECS tasks to be stopped in order for a new task to be deployed

Comment: Can you update codebuild logs??